# wp functions.php doesn't enqueue js scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, enqueue

in my wp theme I'm trying to enqueue a js script. When I load the source code of my page it is nowhere to be seen.

my functions.php looks like this:

```
#LOAD JS
function loadjs()
{
            wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', '', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script ('customjs', '/js/scripts.js','','',true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

I already checked if my footer was included and if the file path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in **functions.php**

```
function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); //Parent theme
    wp_enqueue_script( 'Customc-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );  // Child Theme
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways :

First Way :

```
function loadjs()
{
    wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', '', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script ('customjs');    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

Second Way :

```
function loadjs()
{
    wp_enqueue_script ('customjs',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array());    
}
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

Hope the above solutions will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Function.php

```
function loadjs()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array(), '', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

if you have use child-theme
Try this code in functions.php

```
function loadjs()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/scripts.js', array(), '', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

Answer (score 0):

All of above answers can't spot the different of `load_js` and `loadjs`. Change it to the same and see it's work.